# Unit testing anonymous callback routing in silex

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, silex

I'm approaching 100% code coverage by phpunit unit tests, but the only thing i'm currently not covering is the routing. And i'm unsure as how to test it. Can anyone be of assistance?

I'm using the Silex framework to do my routing in the following manner:

```
$api->put('/update/{websiteName}/{endpointName}', function($websiteName, $endpointName, Request $request) use ($databaseServiceContainer, $sourceRetrievalService) {
    $controller = new RequestController(
        $databaseServiceContainer, 
        $sourceRetrievalService
    );

    return $controller->update(
        $websiteName, 
        $endpointName, 
        $request
    );
});
```

Creating the routing themselves is covered, but not the anonymous callback within.

As you can see within this image:

[image: As you can see within this image.]

The full code is available at https://github.com/ri0t1985/api-creator

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580005/silex-phpunit-functional-tests help?

Comment: No, sorry. That would be a functional test, not a unit-test :)

Comment: Since you create services within the route definition, it would be a bit difficult to test this, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why does it have to be a unit test?  At the end of the day a properly tested application is done by a combination of testing methods, limiting it sounds more like an artificial need rather than wanting to properly test your application.

Comment: I dynamically create the routing based on the records in the database. With a unit-test I have more control over the exact data i use to create that routing, and I can check the signatures of the called methods as well. A functional test would only check if the route can be called without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this no need to be unit tested. You can cover a router by the functional/acceptance tests.

But if you really want to cover a router configuration by the unit tests you can use this approach:

```
// ...

$path = '/foo';

$app = new Application();
$app->get($path, function () {
    return 'foo';
});

$request = Request::create($path, 'GET');
$response = $app->handle($request);

$this->assertEquals('foo', $response->getContent());
// ...
```

Looking for [your implementation on github](https://github.com/ri0t1985/api-creator/blob/master/src/App/RoutesLoader.php), the dependensies is getting from DI here. This will be hard to support, so it makes sense to think about how to make this class more testable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there's no "moving parts" in those route definitions, so they don't really need UNIT test coverage. Just put `@codeCoverageIgnore` on the class, which will get rid of the pink bits on the report. If they're all just lumped into the application class, pull them out into a route definition class first.

For this sort of thing, automate the testing via functional tests. You can use WebTestCases (https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/testing.html#webtestcase) to test the actual request behaviour.

Update:
Possibly to make this more clear... consider if you configured your routes using YAML rather than code them (which is probably a good idea anyhow), you'd not be trying to unit test the YAML would you? No. Cos that'd be daft. You'd functionally test the request itself via a WebTestCase. The same applies when yer route config is done in code.

Comment: I'm well aware that i can simply ignore them from code coverage, however that is never considered best practice. If the signature of the controller would change, creating the route would fail. I would like to detect this in a unit-test

Comment: That's not the job of a *unit test* though, so it's *entirely* "best practice" to not test something with the inappropriate tool for the job. Unit tests should not busy themselves with external considerations like "If the signature of the controller would change", they should focus on the precise function being tested. There are no moving parts in that function, so it doesn't need a unit test. It however can be tested by inference in a functional test. Using a WebTestCase to functionally test the controller will also ensure the integrity of your route definitions.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but i'm using content from the database to dynamically generate new routes. It is entirely the job of a unit test to check if those routes are created successfully. As of yet, i have not found a way to test if the route actually exists.

Comment: This - https://github.com/ri0t1985/api-creator/blob/master/src/App/RoutesLoader.php#L30 - needs unit testing. That's where yer dynamic DB-driven stuff is. The stuff below it probably doesn't even belong in that same function, as it's only tangentially related. I'd extract the looping into `doDynamicBindings`, & the bit below into `doStaticBindings` (or something), & test the first one & not the second one. You don't need to test the $api->get/post/match stuff as that's Silex doing the work there. Then *functional tests* to test the controllers are bound to the routes, & function correctly